# WPF Creating a new ObservableCollection which is connected by Binding creates memory leak (Datagrid)

Tags: wpf, memory, data-binding, memory-leaks, observablecollection

I have a WPF DataGrid bound to a ObservableCollection.

```cs
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BindingVals, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

If i recreate the ObservableCollection like

```cs
BindingVals = new ObservableCollection<Values> {myMainval};
```

it creates a memory leak.

**There are several scenarios where creating a new ObservableCollection might be needed. Is there any way to avoid this Memory Leak?**

If I clear the collection and add the object to it, then no memory leak is appearing

```cs
BindingVals.Clear();
BindingVals.Add(myMainval);
```

See also this Screenshots

[Increase of Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeIai.png)

[Increase of Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8noNx.png)

I'm using .net 4.5.2.

The following classes are increasing

```
ModifiedValue                                                                                       
WeakReference                                                                                       
SourceValueInfo[]                                                                                   
EffectiveValueEntry[]                                                                               
PropertyPath                                                                                        
Object[]                                                                                            
Dictionary<TKey, TValue>+Entry<DependencyProperty, bool>[]                                        
DataGridTextColumn                                                                                  
Int32[]                                                                                             
Dictionary<DependencyProperty, bool>                                                              
DataGridLength                                                                                      
Binding                                                                                             
double                                                                                              
bool
```

I used the following application for testing

XAML Markup

```html
<Window x:Class="BindingDataGridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="120" Width="200"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BindingVals, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <CheckBox Content="Pause" IsChecked="{Binding Pause}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace BindingDataGridTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public bool Pause { get; set; }
        private ObservableCollection<Values> _bindingVals;
        public ObservableCollection<Values> BindingVals
        {
            get
            {
                _bindingVals = _bindingVals ?? new ObservableCollection<Values>();
                return _bindingVals;
            }
            private set
            {
                _bindingVals = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("BindingVals");
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer { Interval = 100 };
            myTimer.Elapsed += CreateVals;
            myTimer.Start();

        }
        private void CreateVals(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Pause)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Values myMainval = new Values
                    {
                        MyVal = "1V" + new Random().Next()
                    };

                    // This creates a memory leak
                    BindingVals = new ObservableCollection<Values> {myMainval};

                    // This does not create a memory leak
                    //BindingVals.Clear();
                    //BindingVals.Add(myMainval);

                    GC.Collect();
                }));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }

    public class Values : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string MyVal { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }

}
```

Comment: IMO, clearing an existing collection and adding a new element is the cleaner approach anyway. You could even make the property readonly, like `public ObservableCollection<Values> BindingVals { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Values>();`

Comment: Hi Clemens,
thanks for the reply.
I already found out that clean and add might work.
The Problem here is it is not Threadsave.
So the question is is there a possibility to avoid the leak in case I need to create a new ObservableCollection?

Comment: Calling Clear is exactly as thread safe as creating a new collection. As a note, you should replace the combination of `System.Timers.Timer` and `Dispatcher.Invoke` by a `DispatcherTimer`. Its `Tick` handler is already called in the UI thread.

Comment: I checked your code. I didn't observe a memory leak.

Comment: You should make sure that the garbage collector has run to make sure the objects aren't just waiting to be collected. I've also noticed that with WPF the objects tend to linger a bit longer than expected but they will eventually get collected. Maybe make a button that forces collection? Let the app run idle for a while, click it and check again.

Comment: Hi, thanks everybody for investigation.
The GC.Collect() is inside of the code, therefore it is collected individually after each run.
I was analyzing the code with a memory Profiler and the results show that it is leaking.
I'm just not quite sure why.

Comment: @Clemens, according DispatcherTimer please see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821686/binding-wpf-datagrid-itemssource-creates-memory-leak